# IE Custom Toolbar is not visible in InPrivate Browsing and Fullscreen mode

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have created a custom toolbar for IE. After I install opens IE9 browser, the toolbar is displayed.

1) When I open InPrivate browsing, my toolbar is not displayed in the browser. It is not listed in context menu too. This happens in IE 9 & 10 versions.

2) When I switch to Fullscreen mode by pressing F11 in IE, my custom toolbar is not displayed.

Are these expected behaviors for IE or do I need to add any code to make it visible.

Please suggest.

Regards,
Santhosh

Comment: And this is tagged C++ because...... your toolbar is written in C++?

Comment: Yes it's written C++,

Comment: Can anybody suggest me on my question?